# Jupyter querying a database without giving out credentials

Tags: python, security, encryption, jupyter

To query a database I can do something like this:

```
connection = mysql.client(user, host, pass, ...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(...)
```

However, suppose I want to share a notebook with a non-trusted user. What are some possibilities for how they could connect/query the database, but not be provided with credentials? Sort of something like a server-side credential injection (if there is such a thing). How would this be done, or is this really not possible?

Comment: The two ways I see: (1) Set up an API intermediary and make requests against it, or (2) create an account that adheres to the concept of least-privilege and configure, export, and send the notebook file with these credentials inside.

Comment: @esqew could you please explain what you mean by #2? "account" being a DB account/user ?

Comment: Yeah, meaning set up a new account in your MySQL instance that has ONLY the permissions required to run the notebook. The viability of this will depend on what functionality is required - `SELECT`s are generally pretty innocuous (unless data exfiltration is a concern), but granting `INSERT`/`DELETE`/`DROP` to this user would likely enable them to wreak havoc on your database (YMMV).